# When I change dropdown value get nearest input textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to display list of values in table format. I pass id in  input textbox  value future I will hide it, and my question is how to get textbox value when I changed the dropdown value.When I changed dropdown it's will update on particular id. Here I have attached my screenshot. Thanks in Advance. i have tried this below code but its will take first id only.

```
<td>
  <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="coin">Coin</option>
    <option value="token">Token</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="hidden" id="comp_id" value="<?php echo $row['company_id']; ?>">
</td>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var type_val;
  $('#type').on('change', function() {
    var fav = $('#comp_id').val();
    alert(fav);
    type_val = $('#type').val();
    console.log(type_val);
  });
});
</script>
```

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPvcU.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
  <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="coin">Coin</option> 
    <option value="token">Token</option> 
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="hidden" id="comp_id" value="<?php echo $row['company_id']; ?>">
</td>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var type_val;
        $('#type').on('change', function() {
          // find parent tr then find #comp_id inside it
          var fav = $(this).closest('tr').find('#comp_id').val();
          alert(fav);
          type_val = $('#type').val();
          console.log(type_val);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: it returns the comp_id for first row of table ,not show alert from 2 second row

Comment: @SubhashiniS, id should be unique for a page, better will be you should give name and  get the value of input field using name

Comment: @SubhashiniS, if you want i will update my answer for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent and next like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#type').on('change', function() {
          $(this).parent().next('td').find('input').val()
    });
});
```

> Note: Don't use repeated ID. Its a rule violation. Use class instead
>   of id to find input.Its take only 1st id because duplicate id is not allowed.

Working snippet.

```js
$('#type').on('change', function() {
console.log($(this).parent().next('td').find('input').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="coin">Coin</option> 
    <option value="token">Token</option> 
  </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" class="comp_class" value="Your Value From Php">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Never use multiple id's of same name on single page.

Generate your id's dynamically like type1, type2 ... and comp1, comp2 ...

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="type1" id="type1" class="form-control sel">
            <option value="general">General</option>
            <option value="coin">Coin</option> 
            <option value="token">Token</option> 
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" id="comp_id1" value="1">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="type2" id="type2" class="form-control sel">
            <option value="general">General</option>
            <option value="coin">Coin</option> 
            <option value="token">Token</option> 
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" id="comp_id2" value="2">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


<script>
     $('.sel').change(function(){
            var select_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var offset = select_id.substring(4);

        var type = $(this).val();
        alert(type);
        var comp = $('#comp_id'+offset).val();
        alert(comp);
    });
</script>
```

Here is jsfiddle link:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tog6bbgu/)